# Cannot find module './declaration?

Tags: angular, frameworks

When I  run 'npm start' I get the error "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module './declaration'

Require stack:
"

Comment: Hello, need the code to give a solution. This is probably due to a wrong import path/ missing package.

Comment: Please add more details and code samples. So we can help you.

Comment: You can use smart IDE available in market like VS Code where it gives you correct option for import whenever you include something from different module.